# Trying to left align img with text but don't want it to go all the way over

Tags: html, html-table

Here's the code I'm working with.  I have it all in one `<th>` tag for aesthetic reasons; I tried making the img it's own `<th>` and then making everything else `<th colspan=3>`, but if I do that not everything is centered together nicely.  If I just don't align the img, it centers above h1, but that makes the height of the th too large for the page I'm working on.

Any help is appreciated!

```html
<tr>
  <th colspan=4>
    <img src="image1.png" align="left" />
    <h1>Cumulative Lifetime Giving</h1>
    <h2>Giving Levels</h2>
    <small><em>* Denotes deceased</em></small>
  </th>
</tr>
```

If I run what I have here, this is what I get:
[image]
Hopefully you can see what I mean now-- I want the image to be directly to the left of the text so that it all centers together nicely above those four columns.
Here's what I want it to look like (I just used Photoshop to move it - this is what I'm trying to figure out how to code):
[image]

Comment: Please specify size of image.

Comment: @GauravMahindra the image size is 170x170

Comment: Do you want your output like you posted in that image above. Please provide a screenshot how you want your output to be.

Comment: @GauravMahindra I added it above. The first screenshot is what it's doing now; the second is what I want it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to use table to align content on a page.
I aligned it using divs :

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <img src="https://www.deltasigmapi.org/images/default-source/foundation-images/foundation-seal360cf5b665726cb08b9eff0000713b9c.png" width="100px" height="100px" />
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;"><h1>Cumulative Lifetime Giving</h1>
    <h2>Giving Levels</h2>
    <small><em>* Denotes deceased</em></small></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly! I appreciate it.

Comment: Good to know it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

here you are

```css
.th {
  text-align: center;
}
.center-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
.center-text {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.img {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
<tr>
  <th class="th">
    <span class="center-wrapper">
      <img class="img" src="https://unsplash.it/100/100"/>
      <span class="center-text">
        <h1>Cumulative Lifetime Giving</h1>
        <h2>Giving Levels</h2>
        <small><em>* Denotes deceased</em></small>
      <span>
    </span>
  </th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is close, but I found what I was looking for above, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Just do this :-

```html
<table align="center">
       <tr>
          <th colspan=4>
          <img src="http://2.media.dorkly.cvcdn.com/10/57/e10409b03f73dfae594e0207caa4b681.jpg" width="170" height="170" align="left" style="padding-right: 20px"/>
                    <h1>Cumulative Lifetime Giving</h1>
                    <h2>Giving Levels</h2>
                    <small align="center"><em>* Denotes deceased</em></small>
                    </th>
       </tr>
       </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, but the div example above is actually easier for me to work in with the rest of the page. Thanks though.